# How to break out of a dolist loop?

Tags: iteration

Is it possible to break out of a `dolist` loop? if not, are there alternatives to `dolist` that don't involve a while loop and indexing a list?

Comment: Pitingly, the `while` loop is excluded. IMHO it is the only pre-defined loop avoiding non-local exit when breaking out of a list iteration. It can be head or tail controlled or anything in between.

Comment: BTW you added `The catch statement evaluates to the value thrown (x in this case), or nil if no value is thrown.` to [lawlist's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53708/2370). How do you throw without passing a value? The `VALUE` arg of `throw` is obligatory. Maybe, you mean `cl-return` where it is optional.

Comment: @Tobias it was poor wording, now corrected.

Comment: I've expanded it a bit further to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option is to use `catch` / `throw`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Catch-and-Throw.html

```lisp
(catch 'foo
  (dolist (x '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"))
    (when (equal x "d")
      (throw 'foo x))))
```

The catch statement evaluates to the value thrown (`x` in this case), or the value of the last body form if the `throw` function never executes. In the case at hand the `dolist` form is the last entry in the body. The optional `RESULT` argument of [`(dolist (VAR LIST [RESULT]) BODY...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html) is not specified. Therefore, it evaluates to nil.

---

As pointed out by @Drew and @Tobias in comments below, the `dolist` function that is available *without* loading the `cl` library is defined in `subr.el`.  Once the `cl` library is loaded, however, describing the function with `C-h f` reflects that `dolist` has been modified as follows:  `:around advice: ‘cl--wrap-in-nil-block’`.  The function `return` (which is an *alias* for `cl-return` that is defined in the `cl` library) can be used to break the `dolist` loop.  To load the `cl` library, begin with `(require 'cl)`:

```lisp
(dolist (x '("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"))
  (when (equal x "d")
    (return x)))
```

Comment: +1. Maybe make clearer that without loading library `cl` the version of `dolist` is different (not an alias for `cl-dolist`). You can use `return` (`cl-return`) only with the version of `dolist` provided by library `cl` (it is an alias for `cl-dolist`). You more or less say that, but it could be clearer - there are two different `dolist`s, and only one lets you use `return`.

Comment: @Drew `dolist` is never an alias for `cl-dolist`. `cl.el` rather wraps `dolist` into a nil-block by an around advice and `(cl-return val)` is essentially `(throw nil val)`. So there is not much difference between the two solutions of lawlist. The second solution is just more elegant if cl is available.

Comment: Do not require `cl`. That is depreciated. Better require `cl-macs` or `cl-lib` and use `cl-dolist` and `cl-return` instead of `dolist` and `return`. Maybe, explicitly state that and give both alternative solutions.

Comment: @Tobias -- I do remember reading a portion of a thread on the Emacs Devel mailing list suggesting that the `cl` library be moved over to the `obsolete` directory of the Lisp source code, but I did not follow that thread to its conclusion.  I will make a note to find that thread and read-up on it ...

Comment: Citation from the [cl info file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Organization.html): "Since the old `cl.el` does not use a clean namespace, Emacs has a policy that packages distributed with Emacs must not load `cl` at run time. (It is ok for them to load `cl` at compile time, with `eval-when-compile`, and use the macros it provides.) There is no such restriction on the use of `cl-lib`. New code should use `cl-lib` rather than `cl`."

Comment: @lawlist here is the thread about cl.el = declaring obsolete: http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Declaring-cl-el-obsolete-td484852.html

Comment: @tobias: Yes, that's what I meant - advice-wrapped with `nil` block (not aliased). My point was to make clear that they're different. unadvised `dolist` from `subr.el` does not support `(cl-)return`, as there is no CL block to return to (and `(cl-)return` is undefined). IMO, this would be a poor reason, on its own, to load `cl-macs` or `cl-lib`. (I personally find the `catch`-`throw` idiom for breaking out of loops etc. very clear - the "block" is explicit/visible, and the tag is essentially the block name.)

Answer (score 2):

The Common Lisp Cookbook has an extensive section on loops.  Among other things, as a substitute for dolist you could try a "for" loop and use "when" to exit. For example:

```elisp
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-loop for i in '(123 3 22 1 309)
  when (< i 2)
    return -500
  do (print i))
```

... output ...

```
123 
3 
22 
-500
```